# Sentiment Analysis with 3 classes (positive, neutral, and negative)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, multiclass-classification

I want to do sentiment analysis with 3 classes (positive, neutral, and negative). I have seen lots of work on sentiment analysis with two classes (positive and negative), but much less so for 3 classes. If I wanted to use a bag-of-words approach and a classifier such as Logistic Regression or SVMs in Scikit-learn, how would this work? What would the steps be for my output to predict with 3 classes?

Do I have to treat each class as a binary classification and do something to combine the results, or is sklearn able to do some processing for me so I do not have to specify this?

Comment: see here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html Also can you add some data and code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possible approaches:

1. Use [multiclass algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), such as logistic regression or decision tree (they are inherently multiclass) or one-vs-one or one-vs-rest wrappers for binary algorithms such as SVM.
2. If you want to exploit the fact that neutral texts are "somewhere between" positive and negative ones, you can use ordered classification models, such as ordered logistic regression in the [mord](http://pythonhosted.org/mord/) package.
3. If you want to exploit the ordering of classes, but want to stay within scikit-learn, I would suggest to fit any regression model to your data first (e.g. gradient boosing regressor), and then use logistic regression on top of its prediction.

Comment: Just a follow up on point 3: Could you clarify the role of logistic regression on top of the prediction? Given predictions yhat from the regression in the first step, are you not again confronted with an ordered classification problem (that sklearn has not implemented)? I assume for this step you would label the yhat from the regression model by "rounding" to the closest sentiment (-1, 0, 1). Why not use those rounded values as the prediction in the first place?

Comment: I suggested logistic regression because it explicitly predicts probabilities. And it may happen that when regression predicts e.g. -0.3, the actual probabilities of classes (-1, 0, 1) are respectively (0.5, 0.3, 0.2), so the most probable label is -1, although the prediction is closer to 0 than to -1.

Comment: Ok point taken. So if I understand your proposal correct it is: 
1) Run regression on original data and get continuous yhat
2) Run *unordered* logistic regression of original labels on one feature which is prediction from the previous step. 
It sounds interesting. My concern would be the information loss due to the unordered model in step 2. Anyway, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. I worked it out as an approximation of classical ordered logistic regression. And you can treat step 2 as just putting the right cutpoints on the regression output, so there isn't much opportunity to lose information.